# removing lines and replacing string in text file

Tags: c#, regex, filestream

I have a text file with over 5 millions lines in it.  I need to run through this line by line and remove certain lines and also replace a certain string.  I coded something in C# that 'works' but it can take almost a day to complete which seems insane as doing a search and replace in notepad++ can do it in minutes.  We need to automate this however.

The file(s) can arbitrarily contain a line

```
"<-comment 1: (more text on the line here)"
```

and

```
"<-Another line (more text on the line here)"
```

I want to remove any line starting with comment 1 or another line...

Also there is a string

```
<tag>&#x2014;</tag>
```

which I want to replace with an underscore.  This should only appear on a line that starts with "LINK:"

The code i have so far is:

```
static void Main()
{
    const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    string filename = @"C:\test\test.txt";
    string output = @"C:\text\output.txt";
    string Startcomment = @"<-comment 1:";
    string Startmoretext= @"<-Another line";
    string othercit = @"LINK:";
    string sub = @"<tag>&#x2014;</tag>";
    string subrepalce = @"_";

    string line;

    using (var filestream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(output, "Clean text file" + Environment.NewLine);                    
            while ((line = streamreader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                count++;
                if(count % 10000 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Batch complete: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(count);
                }

                if(!line.StartsWith(Startcomment) && !line.StartsWith(Startmoretext))
                {
                    count2++;
                    if (line.StartsWith(othercit))
                    {
                        line = line.Replace(sub, subrepalce);
                    }
                    File.AppendAllText(output, line + Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }                    

        }                
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(count + " Lines processed");
        Console.WriteLine(count2 + " Lines written back");
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!!!!!!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The run time is just not viable.

I wanted to have this run under a regular expression that would use a config file we could maintain outside the script should we need to add new exceptions, but also seems to run forever.

```
static void Main()
{
    const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
    string filename = @"C:\test\test.txt";
    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
    xdoc.Load(@"C:\test\RegexConfig.xml");
    XmlElement xmlRoot = xdoc.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlRoot.SelectNodes("/root/line");
    int count = 0;
    string line;
    using (var filestream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\output.txt", "Clean file" + Environment.NewLine);
            while ((line = streamreader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string output = line;
                foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
                {
                    string pattern = node["pattern"].InnerText;
                    string replacement = node["replacement"].InnerText;                           
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                    output = rgx.Replace(output, replacement);
                    rgx = null;
                }
                if (output.Length > 0)
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count % 10000 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(count);
                        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    }
                    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\test\test.txt", output + Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!!!!!!");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

XML config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <line>
        <pattern><![CDATA[<-comment 1:.*]]></pattern>
        <replacement><![CDATA[]]></replacement>
    </line> 
    <line>
        <pattern><![CDATA[<-Another line.*]]></pattern>
        <replacement><![CDATA[]]></replacement>
    </line> 
    <line>
        <pattern><![CDATA[<tag>&#x2014;</tag>]]></pattern>
        <replacement>_</replacement>
    </line> 
</root>
```

How should something like this be done to work in the most efficient?

Comment: Similar to how you read from the file, you should keep the output file open and write to its stream to allow the OS to buffer the output. `File.AppendAllText` will open and close the file each time.

Comment: Also, you can compile your regexps before the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks C, what should i use instead?

Thanks Wilktor I'll look into how to compile it first, this is my first attempt at using regular expressions

Comment: Have you considered recording and playing back macro in Notepad++. It may not be fully automated, but semi-automated with a least amount of work. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following works more efficient as @C.Evenhuis recommends partially...

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\test\test.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string output = line;
        foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
        {
             string pattern = node["pattern"].InnerText;
             string replacement = node["replacement"].InnerText;                           
             Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
             output = rgx.Replace(output, replacement);
             rgx = null;
        }
        if (output.Length > 0)
        {
             count++;
             if (count % 10000 == 0)
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(count);
                  Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
             }
             writer.WriteLine(output);
         }
    }
    writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks.  it has run in seconds.  Just checking the output now

Comment: The document is in xml, is there a way to set an encoding so any inner text such as < sub > is encoded to the hex format.  Generic tags such as these: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwritertag(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if i try to encode it line by line it encodes the xml element and not tags which i want to keep

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get exactly what you need. Let me clear. Your text file mentioned in the question is in XML format, and you need to encode inner texts in this XML file. Encoding, for example, `<sub>` to `&lt;sub&gt;`?? Or you mean any other thing by HEX?

Comment: Does this explain it better? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504912/encoding-html-tags-in-a-file

Answer (score 1):

What if doing it in memory and apply parallel? Something like this:

```
    const Int32 BufferSize = 128;
    int count = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    string filename = @"C:\test\test.txt";
    string output = @"C:\text\output.txt";
    string Startcomment = @"<-comment 1:";
    string Startmoretext= @"<-Another line";
    string othercit = @"LINK:";
    string sub = @"<tag>&#x2014;</tag>";
    string subrepalce = @"_";


    string line;
    string[] fileText = File.ReadAllLines(filename);

        Console.WriteLine("Start time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
    Parallel.For(0, fileText.Length, i=>{

      if(!fileText[i].StartsWith(Startcomment) && !fileText[i].StartsWith(Startmoretext))
                {
                    count2++;
                    if (fileText[i].StartsWith(othercit))
                    {
                        fileText[i]= fileText[i].Replace(sub, subrepalce);
                    }
                    File.WriteAllLines(yourPath, fileText);
                }
            }                    

        }                
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(count + " Lines processed");
        Console.WriteLine(count2 + " Lines written back");
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!!!!!!");
        Console.Read();
    });
```

Doing it in memory might be faster. But make sure you have enough RAM to store.