# Encoding html tags in a file

Tags: c#, html

I have an xml file like the following

```
<root>
</ some junk that is removed in regex
    <element>
        <other>This is some text<other>
    </element>
    <element>
        <something>H<sub>2</sub>0</somthing>
    </element>
<?? more junt that is removed by the regex
    <element>
        <else>more<sub>-</sub>text
    </element>
</root>
```

I have the following code that runs through an xml file and does some cleaning.

```
 public void Main()
        {
            string filename = @"C:\InnerTags.xml";
            string config = @"C:\RegexConfig.xml";
            string outputfn = @"C:\output.xml";

            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.Load(config);
            XmlElement xmlRoot = xdoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList xmlNodes = xmlRoot.SelectNodes(" /root/line");

            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputfn))
            {

                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string output = line;

                    foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
                    {
                        string pattern = node["pattern"].InnerText;
                        string replacement = node["replacement"].InnerText;
                        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
                        output = rgx.Replace(output, replacement);
                        rgx = null;
                    }
                    if (output.Length > 0)
                    {                        
                        writer.WriteLine(output);
                    }
                }                
                writer.Close();
            }

        }
```

This was to clean out and remove some junk lines.

I have now found there are a lot of HTML tags in this such us sub, sup etc

I want to be able to amend this script to encode know HTML tags, such as the ones in this list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmltextwritertag(v=vs.110).aspx

While also preserving the XML tags.

so the output would be

```
<root>
</ some junk that is removed in regex
    <element>
        <other>This is some text<other>
    </element>
    <element>
        <something>H&#x2082;0</somthing>
    </element>
<?? more junt that is removed by the regex
    <element>
        <else>more&#x2014;text
    </element>
</root>
```

But again to stress I don't just want these two tags, any in the list, so italics, bolds, br's etc...

How can this be achieved?

If i try encode it line be line it will encode the xml tags which is worse.

Comment: Would [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx) be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: From your `xDoc` you could select all those `sub` elements and replace them with an XmlTextElement containing only the encoded text.

Comment: I have changed it slightly.  The lines are wrapped in XMl elements which I want to keep.  I only want to target known tags such as sub, sup, < i > etc

HtmlEncode converts the xml elemt tags also which I don't want.

Comment: Are those HTML tags inside input file always between two XML tags in the same line? I mean, for the line `<something>H<sub>2</sub>0</something>`, is the closing XML tag </something> always in the same line with the opening XML tag `<something>`?

Comment: Ah no, it could span some lines

Comment: Then it seems to be impossible to differentiate which one is the real XML tag or an HTML tag inside it. I think the best way here to store HTML tags (or any text pattern, more generally) to be encoded in a list or a file and replace it with its encoded format, which is similar to what you are already doing.